# Adding two conditional random variables on mutually exclusive events $(X|A)+(X|A^{\complement})$

Tags: probability, random-variables, expected-value, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation

If I have a random variable $X$ and event $A$, I can define new random variables $(X|A)$ and $(X|A^{\complement})$.

Is it well-defined to add these random variables together? That is, $(X|A) + (X|A^{\complement}) = ?$

I think the answer is "no" because conditioning makes each of these random variables a function from effectively different samples spaces, and it is not generally well-defined to add random variables from different sample spaces. In order to add random variables, we would need to know their joint distribution, but it's not clear if it is possible to obtain a joint here.

I was toying with this idea because I was trying to conceive of an interpretation of the expression $X|Y$ as a *distribution over conditional random variables*. This would make $E[X|Y] = \sum_{y} (X|Y=y)*p_{Y}(y)$. This seemed plausible at first because a *distribution over random variables* seems like the only mathematical object which can have its expected value taken to result in a single random variable (i.e. $E[X|Y]$ is a single random variable). However, I don't think this summation makes sense - if that is the case, then I'm left concluding that the expression $X|Y$ does not make sense outside of the context of an expected value $E[X|Y]$.

Comment: There is no such thing as  conditional random variable.

Comment: For example, it's common in the context of machine learning to define $Y|\vec{X}=\vec{x}$ where $Y$ is the label and $\vec{X}$ is the feature vector. If the label is binary, then $(Y|\vec{X}=\vec{x}) \sim Bernoulli(f_{\theta}(\vec{x}))$

Comment: As you pointed out, a point-wise comparison between $X|A$ and $X|A^c$ would make no sense. So, I would regard regard $X|A$ as something that stands for the conditional distribution of $X$ given $A$. Considering $X|A$ as a random variable doesn't seem to provide any advantage. Also, as you pointed out, we may make sense of $X|Y$ as a distribution-valued random variable. This means that, $X|Y$ can exist as a standalone object outside of $\mathbf{E}[\,\cdot\,]$.

Comment: @SangchulLee Can you define $X|Y$ as a random variable in the Kolomogorov's model of probability? What is  the sample space and how is it defined?

Comment: @geetha290krm, $X|Y$ can be defined on the same probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ as both $X$ and $Y$ are defined. By the disintegration theorem, there exists a probability kernel $(\mu_y)_{y\in\mathbb{R}}$ such that $$\int_{B}\mu_y(A)\,\mathbf{P}(Y\in\mathrm{d}y)=\mathbf{P}(X\in A|Y\in B)$$ for every Borel subsets $A$ and $B$ of $\mathbb{R}$. Then the measurable function $$\nu(\omega, \cdot)=\mu_{Y(\omega)}(\cdot)$$ is a distribution-valued random variable on $\Omega$. More easily, this is the same as $$\nu(\cdot)=\mathbf{P}(X\in\cdot|Y).$$

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand.  What is $(X|Y)(\omega)$? @SangchulLee

Comment: @geetha290krm, In short, we can define $X|Y$ as $$(X|Y)(\omega) = (X|Y=y) \qquad\text{whenever} \quad Y(\omega)=y.$$ My previous comment explains why it defines a random variable (i.e., a measurable function).

Comment: @SangchulLee What is $(X|Y=y)$? Is it a real number? How to prove its measurability? I don't think any Probabilist (Chung, Feller, Brieman etc)  talk about such things. As far as I know these symbols have no meaning at all.

Comment: @geetha290krm, The disintegration theorem guarantees that there exists a regular conditional probability $\mu_y(\cdot)=\mathbf{P}(X\in\cdot|Y=y)$ satisfying certain criteria that essentially translates to the joint measurability of the map $$\mathbb{R}\times\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})\ni(y,A)\mapsto \mu_y(A)=\mathbf{P}(X\in A|Y=y).$$ In other words, $y\mapsto \mu_y$ is a Borel measurable map from $\mathbb{R}$ to the space of probability measures on $\mathbb{R}$. Then the composition of $Y$ and this map, $$\omega\mapsto \mu_{Y(\omega)},$$ is also measurable (hence is a distribution-valued RV).

Comment: And I agree that expressions like $X|Y=y$ or $X|Y$ are not widely used as standalone notation in the probability-theory literature. (People there surely know how to write down probability measures systematically, such as $\mathbf{P}(X\in\cdot|Y=y)$ or $\mathbf{P}(X\in\cdot|Y)$, etc.) However, they are quite useful shorthand-notation and seem frequently used in other areas. So, why not try justifying them?

Comment: @SangchulLee thanks for your very thorough comments.
1) This notation is used in Prof Andrew Ng's CS 229 lecture notes on page 39: https://cs229.stanford.edu/lectures-spring2022/main_notes.pdf#page=40 ,
2) You say that your would regard X|A as the conditional distribution of X given A, but NOT as a random variable. What do you mean by this? In order to specify a distribution, you need a function from the sample space to the domain of that distribution, and that is precisely what a random variable is, no?

Comment: @SangchulLee

3) If X|Y IS a distribution over R.V.s (as I hoped), how then is it possible to take a "weighted average" $E[\cdot]$ of it if each $(X|Y=y)$ cannot be added together?

Comment: @efthimio, When an $\mathcal{S}$-valued RV (for a measurable space $\mathcal{S}$, such as $\mathcal{S} = \mathbb{R}$, $\mathbb{R}^d$, $\mathbb{C}$, $\mathbb{R}^{\infty}$, etc.) is considered, a distribution refers to any probability measure on $\mathcal{S}$. Then for a RV $X:\Omega\to\mathcal{S}$, its distribution is nothing but the pushforward measure under $X$: $$X_*\mathbf{P} \ : \ A \mapsto \mathbf{P}(X\in A).$$ This way, (1) distributions manifest as standalone objects, and (2) distribution of different RVs, even defined on different probability spaces, can be compared.

Comment: @efthimio, Your second comment raises a good point. And the answer is that "distributions can be added", although in general, what the sum of distributions represent in probability language is a matter of speculation. Fortunately, convex combination of distributions are naturally interpreted as "marginalization" of certain joint distribution, and indeed it fits perfectly into our setting. Now, $X|Y$ as defined in my past comment is nothing but a "random measure". So its "weighted average" can be considered, and it turns out to be the marginal distribution of $X$.

Comment: As a simple example, consider the case $Y$ is discrete RV taking values $y_1, y_2, \ldots$. Then the "weighted average" of $X|Y = \mathbf{P}(X\in\cdot|Y)$ is $$\sum_{i}\mathbf{P}(X\in\cdot|Y=y_i)\mathbf{P}(Y=y_i)=\mathbf{P}(X\in\cdot).$$

Comment: Also adding a bit more intuition on my first comment, think of a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbf{P})$ as a "complete description regarding the behavior of random observation". $\Omega$ collects all the possible outcomes of an observation, $\mathcal{F}$ encodes all the possible information accessible to us, and $\mathbf{P}$ is a function that assesses how each piece of information/description on outcomes is likely to occur (or believable, if you opt for a Bayesian viewpoint). Then a RV encodes a particular measurement process (such as measuring speed of a car passing by).

Comment: Then the distribution of a RV $X$ is nothing but a description of a random behavior of a measured quantity. Saying differently, think of a random variable $X$ (or in general, a measurable function) as a certain "information processing" procedure, and then the distribution is a probabilistic description about "processed information".

Comment: The typical definition of $E[X|Y]$ is an R.V. which results from some function of $Y$. That is, we can represent $E[X|Y]$ as $g(Y)$ ($g$ might be some ugly piecewise function, but it is a function of $Y$ nonetheless). However, it seems your expression $P(X \in \cdot)$ is not a function of $Y$. In fact, it is not clear if it is an R.V. If $P(X \in \cdot)$ IS an R.V., then it is one whose codomain is [0,1]. If we take its expectation $E[P(X \in \cdot)]$ in turn, the result must also be between 0 and 1. This might be inconsistent with $X$'s original expectation, thus violating $E[E[X|Y]] = E[X]$.